# True or false: For all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$ the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{k}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

True or false: For all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$ the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{k}$ is convergent.

---

I say false because it says "for all $a>0$".

Basically this would mean $a \rightarrow \infty$. Taking $a=\infty$ the series would diverge.

---

Is my reasoning correct or not?

Comment: What's $k$????? And BTW, $\infty\not\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I wondered too - not given...

Comment: I'd say that's a typo, and that it should be $k=n$.

Comment: I meant to imply that it's an obvious typo which you should change to $n$.

Comment: I got this task from an old exam, if it's typo professor made, not me. Can't imagine its typo, maybe it's a trap? What would you do in such case?

Comment: But let's assume $k=n$. Would my reasoning be correct then?

Comment: This seems exactly like a typo a professor would make.

Comment: You don't believe me? I can even show you the pdf.

Comment: You said you can't imagine it's a typo, but in my experience these typos happen all the time. Of course I believe you.

Comment: "For all $a \in \mathbb{R}$" does not mean "$a \to \infty$". To say that a statement is true for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ means it is true for $a=0$, and for $a=1$, and for $a=47$, and for $a = -9138047.83274896$, and for $a = 3.14159265358979...$, and for, well, every real number you can imagine. And all the other real numbers you cannot imagine.

Comment: Even if we accept the $k$ and assume it is a given constant the statement is false.  In that case all the terms we add are the same and as long as $a^k \neq 0$ the sum diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is wrong, since the statement says $a\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\infty\not\in\mathbb{R}$.

The statement is indeed false, but you can simply take any $a\geq1$ as counterexample (so long as $a\in\mathbb{R}$ of course).

Comment: @tenepolis: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it should be $a^n$ instead of $a^k$. In this case the statement is false: the series converges only for $a \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Since $a>0$ by assumption, $a\in(0,1)$... otherwise, $a\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: Hi Clement best guy :D

Comment: @ClementC.: Oh yes, obviously. I only saw the part $a \in  \Bbb R$ from the title.